# библиотека react-slick учитывает наличие <></> или <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> и не работает можно как то такое поведение обойти?

Tags: reactjs

наличие <></> ломает работу слайдера хотя вроде бы оно не должно как то влиять на реальный дом или я не прав?

```
            <Slider {...settings}>
            <>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            </>
            </Slider>
```

Comment: ломает,  Fragment можно убрать, он тут не нужен

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов как же я до этого не додумался)))) спасибо за совет но он нужен)) это только ради примера

Comment: А в чем суть вопроса? Как работает Fragment? Если вы в коде добавите фрагменту любой атрибут то на выходе он превратится в div, только тут Slider это за вас делает

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов а вот вариант с тем что слайдер сам добавляет атрибут фрагменту не додумался спасибо а обойти это можно как то?

Comment: завернуть каждый слайд в фрагмент)

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов не помогло) зато узнал из за чего так еше раз спасибо))